# did I find the right K?

Tags: linear-algebra

please do not downvote the question, even if the question sounds silly to you, I'm just a young student who trying to figure out if I answered the question correctly.thanks

so I have the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&4&6\\ 12&15&18\\ k&k+1&9\end{pmatrix}$$

*Using determinants, for which k values ​​the matrix A is invertible.*

[image]

Is my answer okay?
when $K \neq -1$, the matrix is ​​invertible.
maybe I should row reduction the matrix before?

Comment: I wanted to highlight the question,so if anyone wanted to read just the question he was more comfortable,and thanks for the correction.i will edit the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use row operations but your method is fine.

You have made errors multiplying out at the end of your answer. 
$$2(117-18k)-12(30-6k)+k(-18)=18k-126=0$$
and so $k=7$.

The matrix is invertible if $k\ne 7.$

Comment: right,now I did it again and realized the mistake.
thanks for replying you helped me a lot!

Comment: glad to be of help